# account name - field value required issue

Tags: unit-test, administration

I'm encountering an odd problem with the account name field. When entering an account name either thru the UI or in unit tests I get the error required field missing [name], but I am filling in the account name?? There are no validation rules that are causing this. I cannot figure out why it is giving a field value required error when indeed the account name field is populated?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check other validation rules as well as Account trigger ? Error Message could be mis leading. Could be coming because of some other fields might be required.

Comment: I figured it out. A workflow was resetting the account name using several fields concatenated together and if those field values are missing, then I got the required field value missing error.  Thanks for responding and your help! Regards.